# Order by with a particular value on TOP

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to order a list of countries alphabetically but with a specific country on TOP.
After that country it should be ordered alphabetically .
Example

```
India
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
American Samoa
Andorra
Angola
Anguilla
Antigua and Barbuda
Argentina
Armenia
Aruba
```

...........
I tried the answer provided here [Sorting certain values to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079068/sorting-certain-values-to-the-top)
but it was not working
I am using PL/SQl dev tool.
Thanx in Advance

Comment: something like `ORDER BY CASE WHEN (Country='US') THEN 'A' ELSE 'Z'+Country END` should be portable to almost all SQL implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx all for the response.
This way i tried.

```
 SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT L.LOOK_UP_CODE, TO_CHAR(L.CITY) LOOK_UP_DESC
                FROM GHCM_IN_CITIES_MAPPING_DTLS L, GHCM_LOOK_UP_TBL A
               WHERE L.ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'
                 AND L.STATE = IN_STATE
                 AND A.LOOK_UP_TYPE = 'LOCATION_VALUE'
              UNION
              SELECT A.LOOK_UP_CODE LOOK_UP_CODE,
                     A.LOOK_UP_DESC LOOK_UP_DESC
                FROM GHCM_LOOK_UP_TBL A
               WHERE A.LOOK_UP_TYPE = 'LOCATION_VALUE')
       ORDER BY (CASE
                  WHEN LOOK_UP_DESC = 'Others' THEN
                   'ZZZ'
                  ELSE
                   LOOK_UP_DESC
                END);
```

And its working perfectly.

Answer (score 17):

Something like this should work:

**MySQL VERSION**

```
ORDER BY (country = 'India') DESC, country ASC
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da6cf/1)

-- or --

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN country = 'India' THEN 1
       ELSE 2
    END,
    country ASC
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad515/5)

**ORACLE VERSION**

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN country = 'India' THEN 1 
       ELSE 2
    END
```

or you can have more than one specific value at top:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN country = 'India' THEN 1
       WHEN country = 'United Kingdom' THEN 2
       ELSE 3
    END
```

Comment: You cannot use ` for column names. Did you mean `"` instead?

Comment: Not valid in Oracle though.

Comment: @EatAPeach Thanks, added an Oracle version.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no `NULL` values in the `country` column then you can use that one:

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(country, 'India') ASC NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: Beautiful, too, but doesn't scale for "two specific countries on top in particular order", unlike other answer.

Comment: Actually `NULLIF` is internally translated to `CASE` by Oracle so it's just matter of simplicity and pithiness. `CASE` is more versatile but everything has it's price.

Answer (score 2):

There is an another simple way to get the desired result by using `FIELD` function.

Generally FIELD function will return TRUE if the value matches.

For eg., if a table structure is like this,

[image]

`ORDER BY FIELD(first_name, 'PENELOPE')` will return the position of the value in order by FIELD. Since `PENELOPE` is in the first position it will return 1, when the value is not present inside the FIELD, it will return 0,

**ORDER BY FIELD(first_name, 'PENELOPE') DESC**

In case if you want to sort multiple items at the top, then you can use,

**ORDER BY FIELD(first_name, 'PENELOPE', 'BETTE') DESC**

In the above example, the `first_name` with `PENELOPE` will come first, then `first_name` with `BETTE`, then the other values.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `country` 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN countyName = 'india' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, countyName ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you can add a column to your data, add something like CountryOrder, put 0 for India and 1 for all other countries, then ORDER BY CountryOrder
2. If you cannot or have no wish to add another column, you can make this virtually with the CASE in the ORDER BY:

The same way you can add additional countries:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Country = 'India' THEN 0
              WHEN Country = 'China' THEN 1
              ELSE 2
              END, 
              Country;
```

You sort by 0,1,2 first, and then by Country (ascending by SQL default).
This way you will get the result:
India
China
Afganistan
Albania
Algeria
Argentina
Armenia
Aruba 
etc.